# pythonic way to check if my dict contains prototyped key hierarchy

Tags: python

I have a dict, lets say `mydict`

I also know about this json, let's say `myjson`:

```
{
    "actor":{  
        "name":"",
        "type":"",
        "mbox":""
    },
    "result":{  
        "completion":"",
        "score":{ "scaled":"" },
        "success":"",
        "timestamp":""
    },
    "verb":{  
        "display":{  
            "en-US":""
        },
        "id":""
    },
    "context":{  
        "location":"",
        "learner_id": "",
        "session_id": ""
    },
    "object":{  
        "definition":{  
            "name":{  
                "en-US":""
            }
        },
        "id":"",
        "activity_type":""
    }
}
```

I want to know if ALL of `myjson` keys (with the same hierarchy) are in `mydict`. I don't care if `mydict` has more data in it (it **can** have more data). How do I do this in python?

Comment: Why not just do `myjson in mydict.values()`?

Comment: No, that is only true if myjson is actually a value of mydict. 
For example `mydict={'somekey':myjson, ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary of `myjson`

```
import json

with open('myjson.json') as j:
    new_dict = json.loads(j.read())
```

Then go through each key of that dictionary, and confirm that the value of that key is the same in both dictionaries

```
def compare_dicts(new_dict, mydict):
    for key in new_dict:
        if key in mydict and mydict[key] == new_dict[key]:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

EDIT:
A little more complex, but something like this should suit you needs

```
def compare(n, m):
    for key in n:
        if key in m:
            if m[key] == n[key]:
                continue
            elif isinstance(n[key], dict) and isinstance(m[key],dict):
                if compare(n[key], m[key]):
                    continue
                else:
                    return False
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This simple code https://pastebin.com/DXrfEpBW returns `False`. `myjson` holds exactly what I posted in the question

Comment: So you want to ignore the values of the keys if they are not sub dictionaries? You should probably edit your question to reflect that

Comment: If I remove the last key "activity_type" or the keys "type" or "mbox" from mydict, this still returns True

Comment: @Crone Try it now.  For some reason when it tried to compare values that weren't dicts, it was returning true instead of skipping them

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about the values and not the keys you can do this:

```
>>> all(v in mydict.items() for v in myjson.items())
True
```

Will be true if all values if myjson are in mydict, even if they have other keys.

**Edit:** If you only care about the keys, use this:

```
>>> all(v in mydict.keys() for v in myjson.keys())
True
```

This returns true if every key of myjson is in mydict, even if they point to different values.

Comment: I care only for the keys in myjson, that's why i placed all the values in "", if I understood you correctly

Comment: Then use this: `all(v in mydict.keys() for v in myjson.keys())`

Comment: This doesn't work for the nested keys, if I remove nested keys it still returns false